# Isomorphism of Groups (C.S.I.R)

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields

Suppose $(F , +, .)$ is the finite Field with $9$ elements. Let $G = (F , +)$ and $H = (F \setminus \{0\}, .)$ denotes the underlying additive and multiplicative groups respectively. Then which are TRUE ?

1. $ G \cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$.
2. $G \cong \mathbb Z_9$.
3. $ H \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$.
4. $ G \cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$ and  $ H \cong \mathbb Z_8$

I know that $H$ is a cyclic group and $o(G) = 3^2$,  So $G \cong \mathbb Z_9$ or $ G \cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$.

Please tell me about G.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $p$ is the characteristic of the field (I assume $F$ is a field here), then $px = 0$ for all $x\in G$.

Comment: @ Prahlad : Sorry, I am ediiting (F is a  finit field with  nine elements)

Answer (score 1):

A field of order $p^n$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. As a vector space $F_{p^n} \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, $n$ times. Hence here 
$$G \cong  \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3.$$